# Minecraft bukkit player shot another player with a bow

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

How can I detect if a player shot another player with a bow?
I want to get the Names of the players.
So how can I do that?

Comment: watch the chat? There are plugins out there that write exactly who killed who whit what kind of method or who died of which reason

Comment: But I want to detect it per code not ingame i want to work with those values

Comment: I understood that, and meant maybe you can access the chat and parse it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use bukkit [events](https://jd.bukkit.org/), specifically EntityDamageByEntityEvent. Then simply check who the players are:

```
@EventHandler
public void onEntityDamageByEntity(EntityDamageByEntityEvent event) {

   Entity damager = event.getDamager();

   if(damager instanceof Arrow) { // check if the damager is an arrow

       Arrow arrow = (Arrow) damager;
       if(arrow.getShooter() instanceof Player) {
            // the arrow.getShooter() here is the player who fired the arrow
       }

       Entity entityHit = event.getEntity();
       if(entityHit instanceof Player) {
           Player playerHit = (Player) entityHit;
           // playerHit here is the player who got hit
       }

}
```

That's basically how you get the players, now you only need to use that information to print it out in chat or whatever you want to do. Good luck!